# AttributeError when change the command method for a Button in Tkinter

Tags: button, methods, attributes, command, tkinter

I'm on a Python GUI program using Tkinter. In the contructor of the controller.py, I want to give the BackButton the command to open the closeFrame function (command = self.closeFrame).

**view.py**

```
class View(TK):
  def SCPIMenu(self):
    self.BackButton = Button(self.SCPIFrame, text = "Back", command = None)
    self.BackButton.place(x = 30, y = 330, anchor = CENTER)
```

**controller.py**

```
class Controller(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.view = View()
    self.view.mainMenu()
    self.view.mainloop()

 def closeFrame(self):
   self.SCPIFrame.destroy()

c = Controller()
```

I thought something like 
self.view.BackButton.configure(command = self.closeFrame), but then I get an error

*AttributeError: BackButton*

Any ideas? 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that `view` does not have a `BackButton` attribute.
Typically, you are manipulating `self.view.BackButton` before it is created.

An hint: your button seems to be created in `SCPIMenu` which is not distinctly called from Controller constructor. You might want to store the callback somewhere in view and use it as command when you create your button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The problem is, that I want to keep the logic in the controller class. The view only contains the GUI, without any functions.

Comment: Don't get your point, when you write `self.view.BackButton.configure(command = self.closeFrame)`, you are storing in a view element a reference to a Controller function (that what callback are for). I can not see the difference with Controller performing `self.view.backCallback = self.closeFrame` and later (at button instanciation) `Button(... command = self.view.backCallback)`

Comment: I'm a little bit confused now.

In the view class, there are only all the GUI elements, without commands and functions.

In the controller class there are all the functions for the buttons and in its contructor I want to set the commands for the Buttons and the generals GUI.